# postgresql import backup into a new db

Tags: database, postgresql, command-line, backup

I am trying to restore my .sql backup of `postgresql`. I read its documents but I want to have clear simple command for importing my whole db (schema and data) into a new `postgresql` db.

Comment: What you have tried? Just show that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to create a `database` with `template` name `template0` and use:

**Example**:

```
c:\program files\postgresql\9.3\bin> psql -h localhost -p 5432 
                                    -U postgres newDBname < D:\backup.sql
```

**Note**: Be sure with `template` name as `template0` and enter a new `database` name in place of `newDBname`.